# django modelform foreignkey update

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have my model as this:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    EventId = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    Winner = models.ForeignKey('Participant', on_delete=None)

class Participant(models.Model):
    ID = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True)
    Name = models.CharField()
```

I am trying to update an existing instance of the Event object using this in form.py

```
class UpdateWinner(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        e = kwargs.pop('e', '')
        super(UpdateWinner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Winner'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=e))

    class Meta:
        model = Event
        fields = '__all__'
```

and in views.py

```
def update_winner(request, event_id):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UpdateWinner(request.POST, instance=Event.objects.get(EventId=event_id))
            if form.is_valid():

       else:
          event_par = Participant.objects.filter(some query)
          form = UpdateWinner(instance=event, e=event_par)
```

I did check by printing the eventid, correct value is getting passed. but for some reason Winner field is causing some error with the form.is_valid() function and I am getting an error "'str' object has no attribute 'model'". Can anyone help me out here

Comment: Your code contains multiple syntax and indentation errors, also you did not provide the full error message and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't provide an `e` kwarg when handling POST requests in your view, your custom `__init__` function sets `e = ''`. This causes the error when you go to define the queryset - that empty string has no attribute `model`. Try:

```
class UpdateWinner(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        e = kwargs.pop('e', None)
        super(UpdateWinner, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if e is not None:
            self.fields['Winner'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=e))
```

Comment: Damn beated me by 50 seconds haha

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from using that line:

```
e = kwargs.pop('e', '')
```

This means if the key `e` is not in `kwargs` return ' '. Then you use it there:

```
 self.fields['Winner'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=e))
```

Which result in an empty queryset.